# Losing css class after postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css

I have a javascript by which I am dynamically changing css class of a list.

My List :

```
 <div class="BreadCrumbDiv">
            <ul id="breadcrumbs-two">
                <li><a href="#" onclick="changeClass(a1);" class="current1" id="a1">Step1
                    and user</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="changeClass('a1');" id="a2">Step2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="changeClass('a1');" id="a3">Step3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="changeClass('a1');" id="a4">Step4</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
```

Java script :

```
   function changeClass(elementid) {
        var lis = document.getElementById(elementid);
        lis.className = "current";
        lis.className = "current1";
    }
```

Now from my button I am calling the javascript like this

```
 <asp:button id="btnNextODCDetails" runat="server" text="Next" cssclass="Button" onclientclick="changeClass('a2');"/>
```

But changed css style is not working once the post back is happening. I dont want to use update panel. Please someone help me.

Thanks in Advance
Gulrej

Comment: Can u post the css as well

Comment: First change onclick="changeClass(a1);" to onclick="changeClass('a1');"

Comment: are you doing server side processing too? If you are your page will post back and refresh

Comment: Yes Pate, on click of the button I have some serverside code also.

Comment: Hi Shado, I have changed that but still not working.

Answer (score 1):

When you postback data, the control tree will be created again from the aspx mark up.
So whatever the changes you make to the html elements at the Client Side would be lost.

Comment: Correct, but is there any way to retain the css.

Answer (score 0):

You will lose all your client side code(JS) changes when the page is completely posted and rendered again.

If you still need, then persist the information somehow using Hidden field or something and check the same whenever the page is loaded and set it in client side.

You can do this client side code using

jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ // your checking});
```

JavaScript: [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded)

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
  });
</script>
```

IE:

```
object.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", handler, useCapture) //IE model
```

Comment: Hi Murli, Can you please send me some example link. actually I didnt understand.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. I have changed my script little bit. And I called the script on click of my button event.

```
  string script = " $(document).ready(function () { $('#breadcrumbs-two li #a2').addClass('current');  $('#breadcrumbs-two li #a2').removeClass('current');  $('#breadcrumbs-two li #a2').addClass('current1');  });";
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "function", script, true);
```

Gulrej

Answer (score 0):

Use this code on client side just after Page_Load:
It worked for me actually.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, GetType(Page), String.Format("StartupScript"), "<script type=""text/javascript""> GetAttributeName(); </script>", False)
```